# DIY UPS for Home Automation/Energy Management system

Tags: solar-cell, ups, schottky

OK, the original post asked too many questions and I was asked to rewrite the post question. So after reviewing the old post and rethinking the project here it is. So, as requested, I will ask 1 question per post.

---

I have a Home Automation System and Energy Management System. I need to keep them powered during power failures, as they sometimes have issues rebooting in the proper sequence.

Supplying power to these systems is:

- 110 VAC to 12 VDC Switching Power Supply, and
- 12 V (630 Ah) battery power, which is charged by 250 watt 36 VDC SOLAR panel, with a MorningStar TS60 MPPT SOLAR Charge controller. The solar is from another project.

**I want the SOLAR to be the primary source of power.**

Below is the schematic of the proposed circuit, redone from the original design.

**Question**: As the circuit is, can I have both the battery and the switching power supply wired as shown?

I am not sure that the circuit will work, because the SOLAR part will be putting out 14 VDC during the day and the Switching Power supply will be set at 12.2 VDC. The way that I understand Schottky diodes, is that the circuit will use the higher voltage of the 2 inputs, but I am concerned that the voltage difference will create some issues.

[image: Circuit]

[image: 12Volt Switching Power Supply]

[image: (2) 5VDC voltage regulators]

[image: (1) 12VDC voltage regulator]

Comment: It makes me nervous that you keep talking about "5VDC transformer". A transformer does not provide dc, it provides ac. It's also not clear exactly where you want the power transfer to occur...at the 5V and 12V delivery points or at battery output or somewhere else. You need to draw a diagram and clarify your question.

Comment: This looks like a bad idea.  5V LDOs on 12 V , missing AC inverter and battery charger  ?

Comment: The 110VAC>5VDC rated at 10Amps@5VDC. Transfers will be at the 5 volt and 12volt delivery point. Normally, the UPS would activate the backup battery source when 110VAC power is lost. In my case I am looking at having the batteries as my primary power source and switching to 110VAC > 5&12volt source should the battery power drop below 12VDC (battery going bad). I will draw a schematic tonight.

Comment: Do you mean to say "5VDC power supplies"? Are they individual wall warts? I think your use of the phrase "DC transformer" is throwing people off...

Comment: A schematic is essential. Now, I see three 5V linear regulators without heatsinks. You say *"the 5 volt loads total 6 amps"*. If you manage to perfectly balance this across all the regulators, that makes 2A for each. With a 12V input, it means 14W dissipated by each regulator. **This is going to burn.** Please use switching regulators (also because dissipating a total of 42W for this isn't going to please the polar bears).

Comment: As requested I re-asked a single question in the post. All the parts listed I already have in my tool box.

Comment: Thank you for reopening this question